# How to strip/delete all spaces **except between words** in a string in php?

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, str-replace

I saved the values to mysql and I saw spaces like that.

```
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (7, 'James Bond            ');
```

I tried to make it:

```
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (7, 'James Bond');
```

I know make it like that: (But it stripts the space between the words too)

```
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (7, 'JamesBond');
```

Comment: [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the value before inserting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) in your DBMS:

```
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (7, TRIM('James Bond            '));
```

or

[`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) in php:

```
$var = trim('James Bond            ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `trim()`

```
$variable = trim( $variable );
```

http://php.net/trim